# What's the Generic way to push or present View Controller with data?

Tags: swift

Eg Code : Basic Code to push view.

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: K.StoryBoard.courier, bundle: nil)
let vcPush = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: K.StoryBoardID.Courier.courierVC) as! CourierVC
CourierVM.courierInfo = data
vcPush.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
vcPush.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcPush, animated: true)
```

How to get this done in generics?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know how you want to deal with your data, it really ups to you. But I think something like this would help you.

You need to use some base classes to initialize your viewModel, in this case I used NSObject.

```
func genericPush<T,W>(vcIdentifier: String, viewModel: T.Type, vc: W.Type) {
        guard let viewModel = NSObject() as? T else {return}
        
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: K.StoryBoard.courier, bundle: nil)
        guard let vcPush = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcIdentifier) as? W else {return}
    
        vcPush.data = viewModel
        vcPush.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcPush, animated: true)
    }
```